# Where to define files required by many projects in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Let's say I have 5 or 6 projects in my solution. There is a file called fileCopyHelper.cs that basically copies files from one folder to another. I need this file for a lot of projects in the solution and I don't want to keep redefining it in every project? How do I do it?

I tried adding a .cs file to the solution and Visual studio grouped it into Solution items folder.  However I'm unable to access the classes defined in this file in my projects because Solution items is just a folder, not  a project, so I can't add a namespace reference from other projects.

Comment: Sounds like you need to build it into some "shared" assembly that will be referenced by other assembles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new project to your solution, and select the [class library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045(v=vs.110).aspx) type. This gives you a single place to add code that will be shared.

Reference the new project in whatever other projects in your solution need access to the code.

Your setup might look something like this, where the `fileCopyHelper` class is party of `ClassLibrary1`, which is then referenced and used in the main `ConsoleApp1` application:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, But why should it's output type be a class library, how is it different from  Console Application?